# Return value of the JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am doing the online code test. The question is about the javascript function.

Below is a question:

First, answer this code question:
This is a javascript function. Please input the response of this function in the field below.

```js
function test(name, birth_year, current_year) {
  const age = current_year - birth_year;
  const response = name + " is " + age;
  return response;
}

test("jane", 1979, 1990)
```

Enter the return value of the function.
`jane is 11`

This is picture of question:
[image: output1]

When I have submitted the answer is `jane is 11`. The system told me the answer is wrong. May I ask what is the actual return value of the function? Because the online system didn't let me know the correct answer. Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: It seems correct...

Comment: You probably had to do this "jane is 11". Your answer is correct.

Comment: Yup. But not sure why the system said wrong

Comment: "*But not sure why the system said wrong*" computer tests are *notoriously* bad at recognising the correct answer. Usually it's because they only allow one thing you type but it's down to the test creator what is correct. People have failed on questions of the form `2 + 2 = ?` because the correct answer is `4.` not `4`, for example. Or they add an extra space. Or use different notation - `+4` is also a valid answer but won't be accepted. And sometimes the answer field just doesn't allow the characters you neet to enter the correct answer making answering correctly impossible. They are bad.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks explain for me very well. So the correct answer is "jane is 11" ? Need to add double quotation?

Comment: Who knows. Maybe it's `'jane is 11'` with single quotes. Or the question author messed up and wrote `jane is 12` as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure the system says its wrong because you didnt put `"` quotation marks to make it a string data type like `"jane is 11"`

If its still wrong, its either using single quotation marks `'` or the developer wrote it wrong

Comment: Thanks. May I know what the logic ?

Comment: @DavidHolly you can read VLAZ's comment, he explained it very well

Comment: The function returns a value. This could be an object, like a map or an array, or a primitive, like a number, a boolean or - as in this case - a string. When specifying a string as a literal we have to enclose it in single or double quotes. The usual way the console presents a string is with double quotes. The whole thing is very "random", as VLAZ already explained.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and paste the code into the console it literally returns the string: `"jane is 11"`. Looking at your answer the only thing missing is the quotation marks.

If that is the way you entered the answer it would be wrong. Make sure you answer it as `"jane is 11"`, (double quotes) `'jane is 11'`(single quotes) or `` `jane is 11` `` (template literals).

Using quotations or backticks makes sure Javascript interprets it as a string.

Comment: I have console the code. Just show me `jane is 11`. I write console like this `console.log(test("jane", 1979, 1990))`

Answer (score -1):

all you are to write is:

jane is 11

-no quotes or anything, this is for Pi right? I passed with my answer like that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).